# How to set a range of associative array's keys to a value

Tags: bash, associative-array

I was wondering how I could set a range of keys in an associative array to a specific value.

```
declare -A array
array=(
['key1']="value1"
['key2']="value2"
['key3']="value3"
)
```

I can echo a range of arrays using:

```
echo ${array[@]:0:2}
```

it outputs:

```
value2 value3
```

But how could I change multiple values at once to keep my code DRY? Using a similar or different method? for instance a theoretical example:

```
${array[@]:0:2}="newvalue"
```

To change key2 and key3 to

```
['key2']="newvalue"
['key3']="newvalue"
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment will do this on every prior question and any future questions I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${array[@]:0:2}` doesn't mean anything particularly useful for an associative array - it's getting the list of values in some order that bash decides is appropriate (first in first out? first in last out? hash order? alphabetic by index? alphabetic by value? something else?) and printing 2 of them but the whole point of an associative array is that, even if you do happen to know the order that bash stores them in, the values are only relevant wrt the named indices, not the order they're stored internally or anything else so printing or updating 2 out of N values of an associative array other than by their index names doesn't make sense.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

declare -A array
array=(
    ['key1']='value1'
    ['key2']='value2'
    ['key3']='value3'
)

for key in key1 key2; do
    array["$key"]='newvalue'
done

declare -p array

$ ./tst.sh
declare -A array=([key3]="value3" [key2]="newvalue" [key1]="newvalue" )
```